# How to get the values and text of all the options of select element

Tags: javascript

I have a select element with a huge list of options (more than 2000).

I'd like to get the values and name of each option, one by line.

```
<select name='county_city' id='county_city'>
  <OPTION value="51421">City one</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="51422">City two</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="51423">City three</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="51424">City four</OPTION>
</select>
```

What I'd like is,

```
51421 = City one
51422 = City two
51423 = City three
51424 = City four
```

One option per line..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to iterate through the `option`s array, and collect the values & text into a data array, then you can do whatever you feel like with it, for instance print it to the page like so:

```js
var data = [];
$('#county_city option').each(function(){
  var current = $(this);
  data.push({
    value: current.val(),
    text: current.html()
  })
});


$.each(data, function(){
  console.log(this);
  $('#result').append(this.value + ': ' + this.text)
              .append('<br />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='county_city' id='county_city'>
<OPTION value="51421">City one</OPTION>
<OPTION value="51422">City two</OPTION>
<OPTION value="51423">City three</OPTION>
<OPTION value="51424">City four</OPTION>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code :-

**HTML**

```
<select name='county_city' id='county_city'>
<OPTION value="51421">City one</OPTION>
<OPTION value="51422">City two</OPTION>
<OPTION value="51423">City three</OPTION>
<OPTION value="51424">City four</OPTION>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#county_city OPTION").each(function(index){  
alert(this.value);
alert(this.text);
  });
});
```